# How to access a user input email without changing page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want the user to write in an email in the input field, and then I want to take that input when the button is clicked, without changing page, as it ruins my routes.

```
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Add Navigators Email so they can access the Session">

<button type="button" onclick="addNav()" class="btn btn-success">Add to Session</button><br>
```

I need to get the input of a user without changing page using solely javascript.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah using AJAX it is possible, do some research on how to implement AJAX using javascript or jQuery $.ajax() method

Comment: Depends if you mean backend session or like local storage

Comment: so i'm going to grab the email provided, send it via socket through the addNav function to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the element by it's id and then get it's value:

```
email_input = document.getElementById("email");
alert(email_input.value);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gbenussi/dusoctra/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(form).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the reload and the default submit action
    var email = $("#form").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/your/url",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          email : email
      },
      success: function(res) {
          console.log(res);
      }
    });
});
```

And in your PHP (/your/url)

```
echo $_POST['email']
```